# How can I make a stable wrapping around variant function with several parameters?

Tags: java, java-8, runnable

A class has many methods that have the similar structure.

```
public void notifyProcessingAboutReplay(String transactionId, int matchId, boolean replay){
    //    PART 1
    //------------
    // much preparation and checking with possible returns,
    // that all results in a correct item instance. 
    //-----------

    //     PART 2
    // here can be one or many calls, connected to that item
    // and maybe to parameters after the second one
    item.setReplay(replay);
    item.rewind();
}
```

Every method has two or more parameters. The first part of method makes checking on the first two parameters and maybe creates an item for further work. Maybe it merely returns. This first part is the same in all methods.

The second parts of methods differ greatly. They work with that item and parameters after the second one (if there are any).

I would like to separate these two parts in one base method and many partial methods, that will be passed into the base method, probably as a `Runnable`. But I can't call variant `Runnable` as `item.variantRunnable()`, let alone `item.variantRunnable(arg1, arg2...)`. Obviously, my knowledge of injection and `Runnables` is too low.

Comment: AOP before advice?

Comment: @sidgate "I can't call variant Runnable as item.variantRunnable()". Any answers that I have found, cannot be used this way. The previous work longed many hours and its result is negative. The post must be short and understandable and have all necessary info. I do not see any way how I could improve it. According to your empty message, you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Parameter class:

```
class Parameter {
  Item item;
  boolean replay;
  //other params
}
```

And use it as a single entry point to the partial methods:

```
void baseMethod(Consumer<Parameter> partialMethod, Parameter param) {
  //common stuff
  param.setItem(item);
  //set other relevant things
  partialMethod.accept(param);
}

//example use:
baseMethod(this::partialMethod1, new Parameter(replay=true, ...));

void partialMethod1(Parameter param) {
  //do what you gotta do
  param.getItem().setReplay(param.getReplay));
  param.getItem().rewind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems, that could work. I will try and look, if that will be convenient. But I am not sure I'll manage it today.